# Como instalar JFlex, Yacc e GCC para criar um compilador no windows 8.1?

Tags: gcc, compiladores, mingw

Sei que preciso adicionar na path do windows também, pois vou fazer no notepad, então pra compilar direto no cmd, preciso acrescentar na path do windows.

Comment: Acho que a descrição do seu problema poderia ser melhorada. Coloque também o que você já tentou e até onde você conseguiu chegar.

Comment: Tô no ZERO. Eu preciso instalar esses 3 componentes para poder iniciar meu projeto. Mas não consigo instalar. O GCC ai é o de menos, o problema mesmo é o JFlex e o YACC. Preciso instalá-los e adicionar a PATH do windows.